# What's an alternative to using an IF function for long strings of formulas in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

The case I'm working on requires that I apply one of six different formulas on column W for a long list of rows depending on the corresponding row value on column C.

For example, if cell C5 says "A", my formula on W5 must be

```
=(SUMIFS(K:K,A:A,A5,F:F,F5)*8).
```

Then, if C6 = "B", W5

```
=SUMIFS(L:L,A:A,A6,F:F,F6), etc.
```

As I mentioned, I have 6 of these formulas which are way longer than the above as here I just stated them as an example, so it's cumbersome to write all the formulas in an IF format i.e.

```
=IF(C5="A", *bigassformula1*,if(c5=B, *bigassformula2*...)))...
```

Is there any way to do this differently, either through Formulas or VBA?

Comment: I would say you're trying to do too much in a single cell. Perhaps have 6 columns, showing *bigassformula1*, *bigassformula2*.... and then a final 7th column which says "=IF(C5="A",G5,if(C5="B",H5...".

Comment: Formulas can often be made relative to a condition like C5 being either A, B, C, D, E, etc. However, since you've decided to keep the actual *bigassformulas* a secret, it wouldn't make much sense in providing a fix for the made-up ones.

Comment: If the formulas are always the same with known parameters you can always reimplement the function in VBA. Saves you a lot of work, makes it possible to debugg the formula, and if you need to do changes to any formula in the future, you only need to do them in one place.

Comment: In VBA it sounds like a job for `Select Case`, but it is hard to be sure since you have provided so few details.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a table of equations and look them up based on the value like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(G7,EquationLookups,2,FALSE)
```

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

You would want to put the value you're searching for in the first column, and the formula you want to use in that case in the second column.